# Mongo not storing unix timestamp properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I am trying to store a unix timestamp on a date field in Mongo. If I save something like '1450051408' (Dec 13, 2015), in Mongo it looks like this: '1970-01-17 18:47:31.820Z'

Here is my insert:

`Service.user.updateMyDate({myDate: moment().unix()});`

In my Mongoose model, it is specified as `myDate: Date`

Comment: Please add some code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unix()` method returns the *seconds* since the Unix epoch, but MongoDB uses the JavaScript style of *milliseconds* since the epoch.

It's best to just get the JavaScript `Date` object that `moment` wraps using [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/):

```js
Service.user.updateMyDate({myDate: moment().toDate()});
```

Comment: Would it be better to use `valueOf` to get at the milliseconds?  Why does Mongo need a Date object?

Comment: @MattJohnson `valueOf` would also work, but I wouldn't say it's better. Either approach is fine.